# Symfony4 is slow on Windows - What happens after $kernel->terminate($request, $response);?

Tags: windows, performance, symfony4, xdebug

I just made a strange observation in my windows 10 based symfony installation.

I always got rather dissapointing response times, so I wanted to use the profiler to check for reasons.
I found one interesting deviation immediately: Although the profiler sums the totals to about 1000 ms, the browser shows that the TTFB is about 5800ms?

My public\index.php is the same as
https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.4/public/index.php

And here is the thing: When I put an exit() right after $kernel->terminate($request, $response); my browsers TTFB is suddenly at 1600ms!!!

This is mind blowing, cause I always thought nothing happens after the last line in index.php?
Can someone explain, why my symfony route calls are blocked for SECONDS after they are ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this delay must have to do something with xdebug enabled in my php.ini, while the IDE (VS CODE in my example) was not running the debugger.

When I turn on debugging in the IDE (and I remove all breakpoints) the TTFB is as short as with the exit() in place.
When I switch off Xdebug, it is the same.

I think xdebug trying to communicate with the IDE (and not succeeding) must block the HTTP Response for the additional 2 - 3 seconds.